# Angular 4 summing values from child input element

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have one problem which I am not able to solve.
I am trying to create a table which will be counting numbers from inputs per row and column.

[image]

My application structure is :

TableComponent
  ProjectComponent 
   LineComponent 
   inputComponent

Table component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of tableData | projectsPipe">
<div class="row ">
    <table class="col-sm-8 table-dates">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let day of dates;">
                <div><sum></sum></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="sum">0</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of Items">
    <div *ngIf="workitem.teamProject == project.teamProject">
        <div class="item">
            <task-line ></task-line>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And lineComponent.html:

```
<div class="row task-line">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="title">{{title.title}}</div>
</div>
<table class="col-sm-8 table-dates">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let day of dates">
            <table-cell></table-cell>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="task-sum-column">{{sum}}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I am not able to achieve that if I change for example 2. line in 3rd column
sums will recount.

Any advice how to achieve it?

**EDIT:**
Let say i have this code :

```
    <div *ngFor="let prvky of pole">
    <app-riadok></app-riadok>
</div>
<div>sum : {{sum}}</div>
```

app-riadok is component with simple input and when i change value inside input
i need to start ngFor again loop all  components and sum their values and show then in sum div

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference via **@Input** see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Track the changes with **ngOnChanges**

Just be careful model changes on input only fires if its not an object. that is it should be a **value**

Comment: I am able do it for Line where i send from cellComponent value to line component with Emmiter and then change sum. But i don t know how to make it for columns witch are generated dynamicaly. I probably need something like count all values in line and count all values in column but don t know how to start ngFor and get values from child elements in cycle

Comment: Thats actually what im trying to saying. You don't need to pass any parameters or think about their changes. Emitters work only child -> parent. Not parent -> child. so you wont able to track changes in other childs if you dont use the very same model.